# Did Yonathan, King Shaul's son, have children?

Tags: history, genealogy, king-saul

Yonathan died young, during the war with the Pelishtim. Did he leave children?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, he had a son  Mephibosheth ([Shmuel II 4:4](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.4.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Answer (score 11):

Yes, in  [Divrei Hayamim I 9:40](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Chronicles.9.40?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) it says

> וּבֶן־יְהוֹנָתָ֖ן מְרִ֣יב בָּ֑עַל וּמְרִי־בַ֖עַל הוֹלִ֥יד אֶת־מִיכָֽה׃
>
> And the son of Jonathan was Merib-baal; and Merib-baal begot Micah.

So he had a least one child named Merib-baal.

Comment: [Metzudat David](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Chronicles.9.40?lang=bi&with=Metzudat%20David&lang2=en) says that he is Mephibosheth.

Comment: How interesting is that in the second case the second ב is missing.